# expl3 multiply length by a dimensionless factor

Tags: expl3, lengths

In the following code, i would like to print the value of `\baselinestretch * \baselineskip` instead of `\baselineskip` only. I tried with `\fp_eval:n` but that did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=20mm,vmargin=40mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Laborum molestias nam possimus
omnis. Libero sit maiores quas
asperiores nobis est nulla.
Culpa sequi iste deserunt.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_new:N \l__user_verse_skip
\skip_set:Nn \l__user_verse_skip { \baselineskip }
\dim_use:N \l__user_verse_skip
\ExplSyntaxOff

Adipisci fuga et quis dicta
est et odit. Illo aut nulla
qui incidunt necessitatibus
nulla qui. Sunt cumque
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `\skip_use:N \baselineskip` you get the value *already* multiplied by `\baselinestretch`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_use:N \baselineskip
\ExplSyntaxOff

Laborum molestias nam possimus
omnis. Libero sit maiores quas
asperiores nobis est nulla.
Culpa sequi iste deserunt.

\linespread{2}\selectfont

\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_use:N \baselineskip
\ExplSyntaxOff

Adipisci fuga et quis dicta
est et odit. Illo aut nulla
qui incidunt necessitatibus
nulla qui. Sunt cumque

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you show how to do that multiplication?

Comment: @user1850133 Which one? I can't understand, sorry. The register `\baselineskip` is updated each time `\selectfont` is executed (maybe implicitly) and the stated value of `\baselineskip` is automatically multiplied by `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: For the sake of this mwe I simplified the actual problem. I actually need a way to get the value of a length multiplied by a 'real' into a new length variable.

Comment: @user1850133 `\setlength{\mylengthB}{12.345\mylengthA}` is perfectly legal.

Comment: and in expl3 syntax?

Comment: @user1850133 `\dim_set:Nn \l_user_my_dim { 12.345 \l_user_another_dim }`

Comment: @user1850133 And in TeX syntax: `\mylengthB = 12.345\mylengthA`

Comment: Note that three lines `\ExplSyntaxOn \skip_use:N \baselineskip \ExplSyntaxOff` can be raplaced by `\the\baselineskip` with the same effect.

Comment: @wipet This is the same as pointing out that “shipping authority” can be replaced by “schifffahrtsbehörde” to the same effect. You seem not to understand that the OP's code is an example of something they're doing and that involves `expl3`, not necessarily reflecting the real situation they're affording.

Comment: I was jut pointing out that doing this without Expl3 is much simpler.